# ActiveRecord throws DangerousAttributeError for updated_at using oracle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord

I'm trying to create a table with an updated_at timestamp that's rails compatible, but running into some problems

My create table looks like:

```
create table cars (
  id int not null,
  ...
  created_at date not null,
  updated_at date not null,
  constraint cars_id_pk primary key (id)
);
```

The corresponding rails model looks like:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When I try to create a new model I get an `ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: updated_at is defined by ActiveRecord` error.

If I try `Car.instance_method_already_implemented?(:updated_at)` this throws the error. When I do `Car.instance_method_already_implemented?(:created_at)` it doesn't throw the error.

Another interesting thing I found was using `updated_on` works fine (as well as `created_on`).

Anyone run into this before or have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you setting the model - are you trying to set the value for `updated_at` directly?

Comment: I'm not, I want to be able to use the traditional rails "magic" where it automatically sets `created/update_at` when the record is created or updated. I want to record these values.

Comment: Can you show exactly how you are updating the model record to raise this error?

Comment: This is happening on the create, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Same difference - both created_at and updated_at are set at creation.  Can you please show your creation code?

Comment: The creates pretty straightforward, `Car.create(name: 'Some name')`

Comment: Do you have any callbacks set for save or create?

Comment: Nope, the model is as it is above.